# AngualrJS: Why can only bind to reference values but primitive values of services?

Tags: angularjs, primitive-types, angular-services, reference-type

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2dlAu?p=preview) to test binding `$scope` on services. And I found that I can only bind to primitive values but reference values of a service.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="BindToService">

    <div ng-controller="BindToServiceCtrl as ctrl">
        // I wonder why I could only bind on reference but primitive values of a service.
        counterFactoryObj: {{counterFactoryObj}}<br/>
        counterFactoryVal: {{counterFactoryVal}}<br/>
        counterFactoryFun(): {{counterFactoryFun()}}<br/>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("BindToService", []);

        app.controller("BindToServiceCtrl", function ($scope, CounterFactory) {
          $scope.counterFactoryObj = CounterFactory.obj;
          $scope.counterFactoryVal = CounterFactory.val;
          $scope.counterFactoryFun = CounterFactory.fun;
        });

        app.factory("CounterFactory", function ($interval) {
            var obj = [0];
            var val = 0;
            var fun = function () { return val; };

            var addCounter = function () {
                obj[0] += 1;
                val += 1;
            };

            $interval(addCounter, 1000);

            return {
                obj: obj,
                val: val,
                fun: fun
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

In this demo, only `counterFactoryObj` and `counterFactoryFun()` change by time. I wonder how AngularJS binds values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things here that I think are causing confusion.

First, when you return an object with:

```
return {
  val: someVal
}
```

the property `val` of the object is set at the time you return it to whatever the value was of `someVal`. So, when you return your `CounterFactory` service, `CounterFactory.val === 0` - always - and it's not related to Angular's binding.

Second, with `CounterService` service, your `CounterService` instance has `this.val` and in fact it is being updated with $interval (try it with `console.log`). The problem there is that you assign its value in a particular point in time (e.g. when controller function runs) to the `$scope.counterServiceVal` variable. Here, although `CounterService.val` changes, the following remains true: `$scope.counterServiceVal === 0`.

Btw, both `.service` and `.factory` return a singleton service instance as far as Angular is concerned, except in one your return a new-able Function and in the other - the actual instance, but that is just related to what Angular does to obtain the actual service instance - after the service is injected it behaves the same way.

And, finally, if you want to bind to a value - you can, but you need to actually change that value and bind to that changing variable. Here's how you'd do this with your `CounterFactory`, as an example:

```
app.factory("CounterService", function ($interval) {
    var svc = { val: 0 };

    function addCounter() {
        svc.val += 1;
    };

    $interval(addCounter, 1000);

    return svc;
});

// in controller
$scope.counterService = CounterService;

<!-- in the view -->
<span>{{counterService.val}}</span>
```